# How to pass parameters to a packaged java application (.exe)

Tags: java

I need to package a Java program so it's an exe that runs without depending on an installed Java. (from what I read Launch4J or jpackage can do the job) 
And I need to pass parameters to this program program via the commandline.
Finally I need results generated by the Java program back in the calling application.

How do I do that?

Does a Java sitting in an exe have access to command line parameters?

I could do the data exchange via a file, eg sitting in the temp folder.
But I'd prefer not to use a fix-coded filename as it might happen that 2 threads call the Java at the same time...

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EXE generated by jpackage behaves in same manner as your original application except that all the Java / JVM path and options are unchangable, so the built in JVM is launching your class. All command line arguments are passed on.

It does not accept say new system property -Dprop=value but will let you pass all arguments you add to the command line to the `main(String[]args)` of your launch class such as:

```
yourapp.exe arg1 arg2
```

Don't use `jpackage --arguments` unless you want the arguments hardwired into the exe as well. See [Packaging Tool User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Can only be obtained through the parameters declared by the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("params1:" + args[0] + "params2:" + args[1]);
}
```

Comment: Try this way to start in CMD.exe:
xxx.exe param1 param2

Comment: If it runs normally and meets your needs, just write a bat file instead.

Answer (score 0):

In command line:

java Arguments(name of the main class) arg0 arg1 arg2